# C++: algorithm that uses fixed-size buffer of data that are produced in stream, faster than the algorithm speed

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I try to implement this scenario with a producer/consumer multithread pattern and I'd like to optimize synchronization and memory model directive used.
This code originates from a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76635725/memory-ordering-on-a-simple-producer-consumer-example) and its [follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710027/follow-up-on-memory-ordering-on-a-simple-producer-consumer-example), reproduced here.

In the main thread, data are produced and store inside a buffer.
A task `Workload` consumes these data but is slower than the producer, thus it runs asynchronously and can miss data.
As data loss is acceptable, they are stored in fixed size buffers:

- a first buffer receives the produced data;
- a second one is consumed by the `Workload`.
  They are swapped when the consumer is not processing and the storing buffer is already full.
  In this case, the buffers don't overlap.
  The actual task of the `Workload` is meaningless for this review. Here, it merely test the validity of the received data.

NB For each produced data a fast processing is performed (`Run` function below), that may use parameters computed by the `Workload` and updated when it has finished a task.
For simplicity sake, I removed this option from the example and the `Run` function does nothing.

The answer by @JanSchultke and the comments there are leading me to propose a new implementation:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// #define LOG
// #define USEACTIVESLEEP

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
#define MAYBEUNSUSED(var) static_cast<void>(var)
// functions to sleep for short period of times
// active wait but thread sleep has a too large overhead to allow for short
// delays
namespace {
// Iterations per nanosec
double gk_ItPerns;

void EstimateItPerns() noexcept {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    constexpr std::size_t NbIt{1000000};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NbIt; ++i) {
        volatile size_t DoNotOptimize = 0;
        MAYBEUNSUSED(DoNotOptimize);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto delay =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start)
            .count();
    gk_ItPerns = static_cast<double>(NbIt) / static_cast<double>(delay);
}

void ActiveSleep(double i_ns) noexcept {
    std::size_t NbIt = static_cast<std::size_t>(i_ns * gk_ItPerns);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NbIt; ++i) {
        volatile size_t DoNotOptimize = 0;
        MAYBEUNSUSED(DoNotOptimize);
    }
}
}  // namespace
#endif

class CAsyncAlgo {
   public:
    using Data_t = size_t;

   private:
    static constexpr size_t mNbData = 1024;

    size_t mWorkingIndex = 1;
    size_t mBufferIndex = 0;

    // type of data buffer
    using DataBuffer_t = std::array<Data_t, mNbData>;

    size_t mIndex = 0;
    bool mHasData = false;

    std::array<DataBuffer_t, 2> mSamples;

    // Mutex for condition_variable and atomics
    std::mutex mMutex;
    // Condition variable used to wake up the working thread
    std::condition_variable mWakeUp;
    // To stop the worker
    std::atomic<bool> mStop{false};
    // Is an Algo instance running?
    std::atomic<bool> mBusy{false};
    // Can an Algo instance be launched (for testing spurious wake-up)?
    std::atomic<bool> mReady{false};

    // working thread
    std::thread Worker;

    // WorkLoad internals
    // previous seen max value in buffer
    Data_t mMaxVal = 0;
    // number of processed data
    Data_t mProcessed = 0;

   private:
    bool Stop() const noexcept {
        // 1- no synch needed?
        return (mStop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }
    bool Ready() const noexcept {
        // 2- std::memory_order_acquire because needs to synchronize with the
        // store in main
        return (mReady.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }
    void WaitForJob() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "entering waiting state " << std::boolalpha << mStop
                  << std::endl;
#endif
        // 3- std::memory_order_relaxed not possible otherwise it could
        // theorytically be reordered before the previous Workload call
        mBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
        mWakeUp.wait(lock, [this]() -> bool { return (Stop() || Ready()); });
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
        assert(mBusy || Stop());
        // 4- std::memory_order_relaxed because no need to synchronise, mReady
        // is loaded from the same thread
        mReady.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "waked up " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
#endif
    }
    // Check if the working buffer is holding increasing successive integers
    // from some point max value must be strictly greater than the one of the
    // previous call {5,6,7,3,4} is valid if previous greatest value is strictly
    // smaller than 7 {5,6,7,2,4} is invalid smallest value must also be
    // strictly greater than mMaxVal as buffers do not overlap
    void WorkLoad() {
        Data_t Max = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][mNbData - 1];
        Data_t Min = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][0];
        for (size_t i = 1; i < mNbData; ++i) {
            if (mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i] !=
                mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1] + 1) {
                assert(mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1] ==
                       (mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i] + mNbData - 1));
                Max = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1];
                Min = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i];
            }
        }
        assert(Max > mMaxVal);
        assert(Min > mMaxVal);
        mMaxVal = Max;
        mProcessed += mNbData;
    }
    void MainLoop() {
        while (!Stop()) {
            WaitForJob();
            if (Stop()) {
                return;
            }
            WorkLoad();
        }
    }

   public:
    CAsyncAlgo() : Worker([this]() mutable -> void { MainLoop(); }) {}
    void Push(Data_t const Sample, size_t) {
        // writing one sample in current circular buffer
        mSamples[mBufferIndex][mIndex] = Sample;
        mIndex = (mIndex + 1) % mNbData;
        if (mIndex == 0) {
            // buffer is full
            mHasData = true;
        }
    }
    bool IsReady() {
        if (mHasData && mBusy.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void SubmitJob() {
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "SubmitJob" << std::endl;
#endif
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            // 5- std::memory_order_release because needs to synchronize with
            // load in worker
            mReady.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
            // 6- std::memory_order_relaxed because no synch needed, read only
            // by this thread
            mBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            std::swap(mWorkingIndex, mBufferIndex);
            mIndex = 0;
            mHasData = false;
        }
        mWakeUp.notify_one();
    }
    void Run(double const, double &) const {
        // NOP
    }

    // destructor
    ///\details finishing computation and releasing resources
    ///\todo explicitely "close" computation before the end of life of the
    /// object
    ~CAsyncAlgo() {
        {
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "closing" << std::endl;
#endif
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            // 7- std::memory_order_relaxed: on unlocking may synchronise with
            // the lock in wait in this case, the worker will see true
            mStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        mWakeUp.notify_one();
        if (Worker.joinable()) {
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "waiting for last run" << std::endl;
#endif
            Worker.join();
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
#endif
            std::cout << "Processed " << GetNbProcessed() << " data"
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }

    size_t GetNbProcessed() { return mProcessed; }
};

static constexpr size_t NbSamples = 1000000;

int main() {
    CAsyncAlgo Algo;

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
    EstimateItPerns();
    std::size_t acc{0};
#endif
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NbSamples; ++i) {
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
        double period = 10000.;  // ns
        // manage data production frequency
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#endif
        CAsyncAlgo::Data_t data =
            static_cast<CAsyncAlgo::Data_t>(i + 1);  // 0 is reserved
        Algo.Push(data, i);
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        // no more synchro needed as only this thread is designed to launch a
        // new computation
        if (static_cast<double>(
                std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end -
                                                                     start)
                    .count()) < period) {
            ActiveSleep(
                period -
                static_cast<double>(
                    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end -
                                                                         start)
                        .count()));
        }
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        acc = acc + static_cast<std::size_t>(
                        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
                            end - start)
                            .count());
#endif
        if (Algo.IsReady()) {
#ifdef LOG
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
            std::cout << "Ready " << i << " "
                      << static_cast<double>(acc) /
                             (static_cast<double>(i) + 1.)
                      << " us/Sample" << std::endl;
#endif
#endif
            Algo.SubmitJob();
        }
        double res;
        Algo.Run(3.14, res);
    }

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
    std::cout << static_cast<double>(acc) / NbSamples << "us/Sample"
              << std::endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/qxe7TfY6j)

I changed a bit the data managing and the workload in order to make it clearer I hope:

- I've got two circular buffers of same size:

  - one for storing incoming data
  - one for processing stored data
- When the storing buffer is full and the workload is not running, I switch the processing and the storing buffer and I launch the workload.

For the example, incoming data are merely increasing successive unsigned integers.
The workload merely checks that the different processed buffers do not overlap and actually contain successive integers.

Though the test I ran so far functioned (the Workload seems to see only valid buffers), it's hard to be sure with multithreading that it will not fail later...
In the snippet above are included numbered comments (from 1 to 7) about my memory order choices.
Are they valid? Can it be improved?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Lock-free triple buffer](/q/259929/75307), which has a similar use-case in that we should discard data if the consumer doesn't keep up.

Answer (score 8):

## Separate the data structure from the workers

The `class CSyncAlgo` is doing way too much, making it harder to understand, and making it less flexible. I would start by creating a separate class that just implements the thread-safe collection of buffers, preferably templated so it doesn't even have to know what kind of data it is storing:

```
template<typename T>
class BufferQueue {
…
public:
    void Push(T data); // pushes a new buffer into the queue, used by the producer
    T Pop();           // pops a buffer from the queue

    bool Wait();       // waits for a buffer, returns false if stopped
    void Stop();       // stop the queue, causes any calls to Wait() to return
};
```

Note that this data structure deals with whole buffers, it doesn't deal with individual samples. The caller can just fill one buffer, and if it is ready, `Push()` it to the queue.

You could fuse `Wait()` and `Pop()`, by making `Pop()` wait for a new buffer itself. You then still have to make sure it can signal to the caller that `Stop()` was called and that there is no new buffer. You could consider returning a [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to handle that.

## Don't mix mutexes and atomics

You are mixing mutexes and atomic variables. This is a bad idea, as the scope of atomicity is different for variables covered by a mutex and for atomic variables. Of course, if you always keep the mutex locked when modifying the atomic variables, there is no issue, but then there was no point in using atomic variables to begin with. So I recommend you remove all atomic variables, and use `std::mutex` exclusively to ensure atomic access.

Alternatively, you can make a simple double/triple buffering system using just atomics, and use C++20's [`std::atomic::wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) to sleep until an atomic variable has changed.

## You need at least three buffers for performance

You only have two buffers. If you require that the producer checks `IsReady()` before calling `SubmitJob()`, then this limits how often the consumer can actually run. Consider a case where the consumer is just a tiny fraction slower than the consumer; that means it's almost done when the producer calls `IsReady()`, which returns `false`. Now the producer starts overwriting the buffer it was on, but the consumer has to wait for the producer to finish that buffer before the buffers can be swapped.

It would be much better if you had at least three buffers. There is one that the producer can write to, one that the consumer can read from, and if either one finishes with the buffer they are working on, they can atomically switch to the unused buffer. This ensures the consumer doesn't see values being overwritten while it's working on a buffer, and if it's just a tiny bit slower than the producer, it can still run 100% of the time, thus potentially making better use of CPU resources. It also ensures more data is eventually processed by the consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Yet regarding the last one, my goal was this one:

Comment: When the consumer uses a buffer, the producer never write in it. The producer has its own circular buffer and overwrite older data if needed.
I swap the buffer only when the producer buffer is full and the worker is waiting.
3 buffers could be used to avoid circular buffer (but I will loose more data I think than with circular buffer).
On the other hand I don't understand how to use only one circular buffer?
The result of Workload depends on the whole content, it does not consume one data at a time. Maybe it wasn't clear.

Comment: mBusy and mStop are shared and accessed out of critical section thus atomicity is required? No?
Besides I used release-acquire (2, 3, 5) in order to ensure that threads see appropriate values (in the buffer). Yet I will check, perhaps that the mutex already implies the necessary synchronisation. Thanks for having pointed this possible overkill design.

Comment: I understand that `Workload()` depends on the whole buffer, but what is the point of having two buffers if the next buffer it will get is just an *arbitrary* snapshot of the ringbuffer the producer was writing in? This will only be useful for a very limited set of workloads. What if the buffers are images rendered by the producer, and the consumer has to draw them to the screen? The consumer will then very likely get a buffer containing two partially rendered images.

Comment: An continuous stream would be a better analogy: it can be cut anywhere.
Saying it another way is that I will process the last N samples when I'm ready. Even if M>N samples have been produced.

Comment: Sure, you cut the stream at some point, but in your code, the producer can run far ahead enough that it will start overwriting whatever the consumer is reading. So the consumer is not guaranteed to see N *consecutive* samples.

Comment: If so it might be an error but I'm failing to see it. My expectation is that producer only writes within the ```mNbData``` samples of ```mSamples[mBufferIndex]``` while the consumer only uses the ```mNbData``` samples of ```mSamples[mWorkingIndex]```. Am I wrong. Won't such an error fire an assertion in ```Workload```?

Comment: But whenever `SubmitJob()` is called, `mBufferIndex` and `mWorkingIndex` are swapped... ah I see now that you are supposed to check first if `IsReady()` returns `true`? This is very unclear from the code, and such a thing should be enforced by the class.

Comment: Yes. But your suggestion would be to push ```IsReady``` inside of ```SubmitJob```? I actually thought of that and call it ```TrySubmitJob```.
I definitely agree that above code is not foolproof and should be hardened. Yet my primary purpose was to get the synchronization right.
By the way I will post a variant based on your remark about atomics and mutexes.

Comment: follow-up on this review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286138/c-algorithm-that-uses-fixed-size-buffer-of-data-that-are-produced-in-stream)

Comment: @Oersted: Having 3 or more buffers is going in the direction of a lock-free queue in a circular buffer.  There are many existing implementations; you might want to pick one apart and see how it works, or just use one to pass pointers to buffers.  [Lock-free Progress Guarantees in a circular buffer queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907210) is an analysis and discussion of a multi-producer multi-consumer queue design (which uses sequence-numbers inside each bucket to reduce contention between writers and readers, among other reasons.)  SPSC can be simpler.